# manually open context manager

Tags: python, with-statement, contextmanager

My question is, how can I execute any context manager without using `with`?

---

Python has the idea of context managers,

instead of

```
file = open('some_file', 'w')
try:
    file.write('Hola!')
finally:
    file.close()
# end try
```

you can write

```
with open('some_file', 'w') as opened_file:
    opened_file.write('Hola!')
# end with
```

While in most cases the second one is the golden solution, however for the specific cases of testing in unit tests as well exploring in the interactive console, the first one can be much better used, as you can write it line by line.

```
>>> file = open('some_file', 'w')
>>> file.write('Hola!')
>>> file.close()
```

My question is, how can I execute any `with` context manager like this, best suited for exploring?

---

My actual use case follows below, but please try to **give a answer which is generic** and will work for other context managers too.

```
import flask

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

with app.test_request_context('/?name=Peter'):
    assert flask.request.path == '/'
    assert flask.request.args['name'] == 'Peter'
```

[from flask docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/testing/#other-testing-tricks)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can still use `with` syntax in the interactive console, however a context is based on 2 magic methods `__enter__` and `__exit__`, so you can just use them:

```
class MyCtx(object):
  def __init__(self, f):
    self.f = f

  def __enter__(self):
    print("Enter")
    return self.f

  def __exit__(*args, **kwargs):
    print("Exit")

def foo():
  print("Hello")
```

usually you do:

```
with MyCtx(foo) as f:
  f()
```

Same as:

```
ctx = MyCtx(foo)
f = ctx.__enter__()
f() 
ctx.__exit__()
```

Here you have the [live example](https://repl.it/@danielsanchez1/KaleidoscopicNuttyDatabases)

Remember that contexts `__exit__` method are used for managing errors within the context, so most of them have a signature of `__exit__(exception_type, exception_value, traceback)`, if you dont need to handle it for the tests, just give it some `None` values:

```
__exit__(None, None, None)
```

Comment: The example works very good, but in my flask case I get `TypeError: __exit__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'exc_type', 'exc_value', and 'tb'`. I read about leaving out `exception_type`, `exception_value`, and `traceback` arguments for the `__exit__` function [being considered as anti-pattern](https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/correctness/exit_must_accept_three_arguments.html#exit-must-accept-3-arguments-type-value-traceback).  Could you give some more insights related to that, and how to handle it?

Comment: @luckydonald, for that you would have to use a `try/except` block after `__enter __`and capture the exception, also use traceback and give the results to the `__exit__` method.

Comment: but in case of no exception it would be `(None, None, None)`?

Comment: @luckydonald, exactly

Comment: would you mind updating your answer with that additional information, as the need for those parameters seem to exist in most `__exit__` implementations.

Comment: @luckydonald, ofc, added

Answer (score 1):

You can call `app.test_request.context('/?name=Peter')` to a variable (e.g. `ctx`), and then call `ctx.__enter__()` on it to enter the context manager, and `ctx.__exit__(None, None, None)` to perform the cleanup. Note that you lose the safety guarantees of context managers, unless you put the `ctx.__exit__` in a `finally` clause.